# Using docker context to a mac

Tags: docker, macos, ssh, path

I had been trying to create a context to deploy a few containers from my main Mac to another another but I have been getting a weird error.

So, I have two Macs, one iMac (Late 2013) (here will be called Enterprise) and one Macbook Pro (Mid 2015) (here will be called Defiant). Defiant is my main computer and I want to deploy my container to Enterprise in order to not overload Defiant memory. I have been working with docker context to achieve that. Currently, I have Enterprise running Docker v20.10.16 and Defiant running v20.10.16.

I have created the context on Defiant and after I run the `docker context use enterprise` and when I run `docker container ls` I get the following error:

```
error during connect: Get "http://docker.example.com/v1.24/containers/json": command [ssh -l rafaelguerra -- Enterprise.local docker system dial-stdio] has exited with exit status 127, please make sure the URL is valid, and Docker 18.09 or later is installed on the remote host: stderr=zsh:1: command not found: docker
```

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Thanks

UPDATE:

Weird thing I just found out, when logged into Enterprise and run `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` however when I run `ssh rafaelguerra@enterprise.local 'echo $PATH'` I got the following `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

I don't have a clue for a reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for the problem, all commands docker run are run within ssh not with a permanent ssh session. So, zsh does not load the correct PATH when the command is run within the ssh. Therefore, the only thing I need to do was setting the correct PATH inside of the ~/.zshenv file and everything is working now.